# MySQL GROUP BY order when no ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

In MySQL, what order is the resultset if `GROUP BY` is used but `ORDER BY` is *not* specified?

I have inherited code with queries like:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

(Actually the `SELECT` statement can be much more complex than that, involving `JOIN`s etc., but let's start with the base principle.)  Note that there is no `ORDER BY`.

In, say, SQL Server BOL, I am told:

> The GROUP BY clause does not order the result set. Use the ORDER BY
>   clause to order the result set.

I have been unable to find a statement as to whether MySQL `GROUP BY` does or does not promise a particular ordering from `GROUP BY` alone?  If a MySQL reference could be provided to back up any answer that would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY
>   columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the
>   overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
> ```
>
> Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting (that is, sorting in the absence
>   of ASC or DESC designators) is **deprecated**. To produce a given sort
>   order, use explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns or
>   provide an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!